# Jquery button text effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to animate text inside button?. I want to implement text effect. This is my code.

```
$(function () {
    var string = "Shop Now";
    var q = jQuery.map(string.split(''), function (letter) {
        return $('<span>' + letter + '</span>');
    });

    var dest = $('#fadeIn');

    var c = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function () {
        q[c].appendTo(dest).hide().fadeIn(100);
        c += 1;
        if (c >= q.length) clearInterval(i);
    }, 30);
});
```

Here is my [button code](http://jsfiddle.net/veDY6/29/) and i want to implement this effect. Is there a way to animate text button effect?.

Comment: I think you can't use animation for `<input type="button" />` like that. Maybe you should try `<a href="something"><span>your text here</span></a>`, style the `a` tag to look like a button, then animate nested span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated you fiddle check now: 
http://jsfiddle.net/JeekOnline/veDY6/31/

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><div id="fadeIn">  </div></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I hope, this is what exactly you required.

Comment: This is perfect can i also move my car image to the middle? right now its now in the center when i increase image position to 80 $("#Image_Car").animate({left: "80" then it moves to the center but again comes back to left position

Comment: you have removed the slide to right method but i want to keep that one as well it is like entering from the left and then slide to right

Comment: one more thing button size is changed i want to keep my button size same. By default button size to be Learn more and then that effect to rewrite button effect but without changing button size.

Comment: yup this one is cool can you something with the button size as well?

Comment: Thanks buddy this one is what i was looking for can you tell me about button text as well. By default its Learn More and then i am changing the text of button to rewrite it but my button size is changing

Comment: yes i have done it just last question is it possible to do fade in animation on Striped Bag

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify what exactly look for?

Comment: i want fade in animation on headline1Txt id is it possible

Comment: can you see my update code.jsfiddle.net/veDY6/37 i have set learn more by default then i am clearing the text and applying that effect to rewrite Learn more but it is not working. Am i doing something wrong i am using delay as well .                                      $('#fadeIn').text('Learn More');
$('#fadeIn').delay(50).text('');

Comment: yes this one was perfect and you are a champ.!! can you tell me how you did this and can you recommend me any books/ tutorials so that i can get better in css/jquery